# Module java.se.ee not found (M1 MacBook)

Tags: java, macos, scala, apple-m1

I have encountered an error while trying to install scala on my M1 mac.

I've used the terminal commands from the official Getting Started guide.

```
curl -fL https://github.com/VirtusLab/coursier-m1/releases/latest/download/cs-aarch64-apple-darwin.gz | gzip -d > cs && chmod +x cs && (xattr -d com.apple.quarantine cs || true) && ./cs setup
```

I got the result, that all the needed packages had been installed. I rebooted the computer. Then I tried to run

```
scala --version
```

and got the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
```

I would be glad if someone could help me)

Answer (score 0):

1. Running these commands helped to fix `scala` but `scalac` still crashes

```
brew reinstall openjdk && brew reinstall scala
```

2. Downgrading Java to version 9 helped:

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk9
```

Add this line to `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9)
```

Restart your terminal or `source .bash_profile`

It should work now

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Scala "Getting Started"](https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html) if you install by hand, you need Java 8 or Java 11.

Installing and using Java 9 (in 2023) is a **bad idea** because Java 9 has been end-of-life for over 5 years.